# DW Easy Rotator - text in div not showing up

Tags: css, plugins, dreamweaver

This page uses a plugin from Dreamweaver called Easy Rotator. It is current being used to display an image gallery. There is a div to the right of the image that has text in it, but it is not showing the text. I am not sure why this is the case. I have tried using the CSS inspector to track down the problem with not luck. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Live page: http://www.securitybankusa.com/art

Comment: Not related to your question - but that page is nearly 60MB!! Optimise your images for the sake of everyone.

Comment: @NickR I will look into that. I did not build this site. I am fixing this page for the client. Thanks for the heads up though.